# Proper SEO when dealing with duplicate content/article

Tags: seo

I have a blog post I wrote which another site wishes to post on their site, verbatim.

I know having identical content is an SEO "ding". Is there a way to tell Google that the new site is referencing the old site? Such as a meta tag for "source_url" or something like that?

Or should the new place simply just add a few lines or a graph at the top stating this is copied from a previous blog? Is that enough to satisfy Google's bot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is exactly what [canonical URLs](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/12/handling-legitimate-cross-domain.html) are for. It tells Google which site/page is the original author.

Comment: So would I just ask them to place this in their page: `<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.mycontent.com/" />`

Comment: That would be all you need to do. But getting a real link back would be great, too. ;)